# How to get particular set of values from database in Php using PDO Fetch method?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

I have a library.php where functions are written, a particular function get_channels is written to get all values which belong to customer_id. I'm employing PDO and I want to execute and get value in this function and result has to be displayed in frontend on another page.  But this function is not displaying any name of table belonging to customer id.

Function in library.php

```
public function get_channels($cust_id)
{
    try {
        $db = DB();
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sensor_table WHERE customer_id=:customer_id");
        $query->bindParam("customer_id", $cust_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();   
        return $query;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Code in Frontend webpage:

```
<div id="main-content">


            <?php 

            $count=$app->get_channels_count($customer->customer_id);
            $values=$app->get_channels($customer->customer_id);
            $channel_name=$values->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            echo $channel_name;
            for($i=0;$i<$values->rowCount();$i++)
            {

            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="card alert">
                            <div class="products_1 text-center">
                                <div class="pr_img_price">
                                    <div class="product_img">
                                        <img src="assets/images/product_1/download.jpg" alt="" />
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="product_details">
                                    <div class="product_name">
                                        <h4><?php echo $channel_name['table_name'];  ?></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product_des">
                                        <p>Vimply dummy text the printing and type setting indust.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="prdt_add_to_cart">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded  m-l-5">add to cart</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /# card -->
                    </div>

                <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Don't use `rowcount` with PDO for `select` queries. You also are fetching it as an object, not an array.

Comment: `$values` is iterable, so you can use `foreach` on it.